# Lipschitz condition not satisfied

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

[image]

To show there is no contradiction to existence and uniqueness

$\displaystyle\frac{|f(x,u)-f(x,v)|}{|u-v|}= \displaystyle\frac{|x||u^{1/2}-v^{1/2}|}{|u-v|}=\frac{|x|}{u^{1/2}+v^{1/2}}$

I understand that for small $u$ and $v$ the above expression is unbounded. However, what is this actually saying? i.e does this imply $y$ is not lipschitz at $y=0$? If so why is this?

Answer (score 1):

For $f(x, \cdot)$ to be Lipschitz there must exist a constant $L > 0$ s.t. for every pair $u$, $v$ there holds $|f(x, u) - f(x, v)| \leq L |u - v|$. Rewriting this as a fraction you get the equivalent condition that $$\frac{|f(x, u) - f(x, v)|}{|u-v|} \leq L$$
must hold for every $u, v$. Your argument shows that such a constant cannot exist, hence $f$ is not Lipschitz.

(By the way: Lipschitz continuity isn't a property which is defined at a single point, so saying that $f$ is not Lipschitz at $0$ doesn't make sense.)

Comment: I meant locally lipschitz. Doesn't the fact that locally lipschitz is enough to guarantee existence and uniqueness mean that I just need to show that  $f$ is not locally lipschitz at a point, so that I have not contradicted the existence and uniqueness theorem?

Comment: Yes, your reasoning is sufficient.

Comment: But why does what I have written in the OP say that $y$ is not locally lipschitz at $0$?

Comment: Because your argument shows that the fraction goes to infinity for $u, v \to 0$. Therefore it cannot be bounded by any constant $L$ (constant in the sense that must be independent of $u$ and $v$).